# What is the Z ending on date strings like 2014-01-01T00:00:00.588Z

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format

Im doing a fetch to get a date from a database in java (the date should always be `2014-01-01T00:00:00`).  I'm getting the following time returned: `2014-01-01T00:00:00.588Z`.

My questions is, what is the *"`588Z`"* at the end? and would this number be different the retrieve was done in a different timezone? i.e. would the number 588 be a different number in a different time zone.

Thanks for any help I may get.

Comment: Time zone identifier...

Comment: 588 is the millisecond value and it does not depend on time zone.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, I appreciate it I still have one other question though.  Each time I get the date the number 588Z changes to a different number when the date I am retrieving is always the same.  What is the milliseconds from?  The reason I need to know this is that I am comparing this value in a static xml page and that portion of the time is always changing hence never matching my static xml.

Comment: I was being silly regarding the milliseconds, Sorry.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: `Z` stands for [Zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), zero hours timezone offset. `T` stands for time (just to separate the date and time). See [ISO8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time format).

Comment: Z is the sound of a bee passing by...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The ***`Z`*** stands for the *zero UTC offset*.

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space.
>   
>   Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset.
>   
>   "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z", while "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

The portion immediately before the ***`Z`*** translates into fraction of second; here, **`588`**.

*From your question above, `00:00:00.588` means "about a half second past midnight", with the last three digits after the period, **`588`**, translating: [milliseconds](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).*

*... more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) on (ISO 8601 standard).*

Answer (score 5):

Z stands for UTC (that is GMT, but standard): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: A for apple, B for Ball, Z for UTC

Answer (score 5):

Z is shorthand for the UTC timezone.