# Date conversion: add UTCOffset to existing timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I have date which is in the format of(example) Date = 2023-01-09T23:51:44.595Z
and I have utcOffset String utcOffset = "UTC +6"

I want output as 2023-01-10T05:51:44.595Z in Date format.

How to achieve this??

I should add UTC offset to existing date.

Tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String rawDate = "2023-01-09T23:51:44.595Z";
        String utcOffset = "UTC +6";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ROOT);
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(rawDate);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ROOT);
        String v = formatter1.format(date);
        System.out.println("Original raw date::::::::::"+v);
        
        System.out.println("utcOffset::::::::::"+utcOffset);

        Date triggerTime = date;
        String onlyHoursAndMin = StringUtils.strip(utcOffset, "UTC ");

        String[] split = onlyHoursAndMin.split(":");
        int hours = Integer.parseInt("0");
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt("0");
        if (split.length == 2) {
            hours = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        } else if (split.length == 1) {
            hours = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            minutes = Integer.parseInt("0");
        }

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
        calendar.setTime(triggerTime);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        Date s = calendar.getTime();
        
        SimpleDateFormat utcFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ROOT);
        String newDate = utcFormatter1.format(s);
        System.out.println("Date in string format::::::::::::::"+newDate);
        
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ROOT);
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ROOT);
        Date aaa = format1.parse(newDate);
        String bbb = format2.format(aaa);
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::"+aaa);
        System.out.println("Date in correct format::::::::::::::"+format2.format(aaa));
        
    }
```

but finale Date format is Tue Jan 10 05:51:44 IST 2023 which is not expected.

and when build I am getting below error as well:
Forbidden method invocation: java.util.Calendar#getInstance(java.util.TimeZone) [Uses default locale or time zone]

Comment: Do you know whether that’s a message from [forbidden-apis](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis/wiki)? It could sound like it.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar` and`TimeZone`. Those classes are troublesome and long outdated. Use `Instant`, `ZoneOffset` and `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: If you meant to ask for a `java.util.Date` with the format you mentioned, that is neither possible nor what you should want. Use a date-time object (for example an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `Date` as I said) to hold a *value*. When you need to give output in a specific format, use a formatter for formatting that value into a `String` in the desired format. As an aside only, `Instant.toString()` prints in that format, `OffsetDateTime.toString()` will if the offset is 0; `Date.toString()` *never* will.

Comment: Is the UTC offset always a whole number of hours? Could it be for example +5:30 or +5:45?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to move away from the legacy API (java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, etc.), it is cumbersome and error prone. Since java 8 the modern date-time API, [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), is available. With it the task would be quite trivial.

```
String date = "2023-01-09T23:51:44.595Z";
OffsetDateTime oldDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
System.out.println("old - " + oldDateTime);
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(6);
OffsetDateTime newDateTime = oldDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(offset);
System.out.println("new - " + newDateTime);
```

Prints time - `2023-01-10T05:51:44.595+06:00`.

Note that it ends with `+06:00`, not `Z`. `Z` at the end of a date-time string means `Zulu`, which indicates that the time is in UTC - [What is the Z ending on date strings like 2014-01-01T00:00:00.588Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840670/what-is-the-z-ending-on-date-strings-like-2014-01-01t000000-588z). Since resulting time is UTC + 6 hours, a date sting `2023-01-10T05:51:44.595Z` would be **incorrect**.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`

1. `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format e.g. your date-time string, `2023-01-09T23:51:44.595Z` which can be directly parsed into an `OffsetDateTime`.
2. Your offset string is not in the ISO 8601 standard format. The standard format is `+/-HH:mm:ss` or `Z` which refers to `+00:00` offset. In most cases, you will see `+/-HH:mm` e.g. `+06:00`. You can choose any basic string manipulation technique to get the hours and minutes from your string and create a `ZoneOffset` instance using them. I have used one which I have found easy to do.

The rest of the code is straightforward.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2023-01-09T23:51:44.595Z";
        String utcOffset = "UTC +6";
        int offsetHour = Integer.parseInt(utcOffset.replaceAll("[^0-9+-]", ""));
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(offsetHour);
        OffsetDateTime odtGiven = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        OffsetDateTime odtDesired = odtGiven.withOffsetSameLocal(zoneOffset)
                                        .withOffsetSameInstant(zoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtDesired);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2023-01-09T17:51:44.595Z
```

Note that `2023-01-10T05:51:44.595Z` does not make sense without am/pm marker as you mean `05:51:44.595 pm`. You can use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the above output in your desired way.

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/l2YdsV)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

I liked the alternative way [suggested by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280511/date-conversion-add-utcoffset-to-existing-timezone/75285083?noredirect=1#comment132847275_75285083) to parse the offset string. Given below is the solution based on his suggestion:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2023-01-09T23:51:44.595Z";
        String utcOffset = "UTC +6";
        DateTimeFormatter offsetFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .appendLiteral("UTC ")
                                            .appendOffset("+H:mm", "+0")
                                            .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = offsetFormatter.parse(utcOffset, ZoneOffset::from);
        // Rest of the lines are the same as the above code
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8WZj5C)

Comment: Good answer. I like to leave as much work as possible for the formatters, so even though it’s wordy my personal preference would to be declare `DateTimeFormatter offsetFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .appendLiteral("UTC ") .appendOffset("+H:mm", "+0") .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);`. Then parse the offset as `offsetFormatter.parse(utcOffset, ZoneOffset::from)`. Presented as a possible alternative for everyone to make their own preferred pick.